# Hide the vertical scroll bar while continuing to scroll

Tags: css, scroll, scrollbar, hidden

I hide the vertical scrollbar by adding below in CSS

```
overflow: hidden;
```

then to continue to enjoy the scroll without displaying the scroll bar, I type the following code :

```
overflow-y: scroll;
scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
```

Of course, the scroll bar reappears and the scroll works.

I want to hide the scroll bar but I can't. I have tried a lot of tricks without success.

Thank you for enlightening me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `::-webkit-scrollbar`.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.div1 {
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: green;
}
.div2 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  scroll me
</div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```